# filter profilable scripts in DevTools (blackboxing)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, black-box

i try to investigate bug on existing site so i use devtools "Perfomance" and JavaScript profiler to understand chain of call. the problem that too many scripts are in report. when debugging there is a good feature - blackboxing, which help to hide third-party scripts. But is there some way to blackbox in profiler?

Answer (score 0):

DevTools tech writer here.

> But is there some way to blackbox in profiler?

I asked the team about this. There was an experiment around this feature, but it was removed. So it's currently not possible.

If you press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (Windows, Linux, Chrome OS), you can open the Performance panel's search box. Maybe that will help?